# Unable to get visible texteditor in other viewcolumn

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to open the active file in a new viewcolumn, and fold a tag. The folding commands work fine in `activeTextEditor`:

```ts
// Fold based on linenumber
let range = editor.document.lineAt(lineNumber).range;
editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(range.start, range.end);
editor.revealRange(range);
commands.executeCommand('editor.fold');
```

Now I would like to do the same in a newly opened file:

```ts
// Open the same file in a new column
// at this time editor.ViewColum is One
commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', Uri.file(editor.document.fileName), ViewColumn.Two);

// Try to get that editor
let newEditor = vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.find(x=> x.viewColumn===viewColumn.Two && x.document.fileName===fileName)
```

The problem is that `newEditor` is not found, becouse the newly opened document has `ViewColumn` `undefined`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vs commands returns a promise. Needed to await that and everything works fine.